# Return the last element in the node list

Tags: java, dnode

I currently have the following Node List: `{3,2,5,6,2,5}`

When I invoke: `trailer.getPrev()` the output is 2. The problem is I want to return 5, how do I do this.

I have tried: return trailer; but then I get an error: The trailer node is not a valid position

Thanks for any help.

EDIT: Its a NodePositionList

Comment: Without knowing the classes and API you are using this is like asking us 'How long is this piece of string I'm holding here?'.

Answer (score 1):

If it's an implementation of [NodeList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/NodeList.html), you should be able to access the last item with

```
yourList.item(yourList.getLength()-1);
```

EDIT:

With a NodePositionList, regarding the [documentation](http://net3.datastructures.net/doc4/net/datastructures/NodePositionList.html#checkPosition%28net.datastructures.Position%29), you should be able to do the same with something like:

```
yourList.checkPosition(yourList.last());
```

that will return a DNode. `last()` only returns the position of the last item in the list.

Comment: I have tried to enter that and it gives errors that the methods do not exist.

Comment: What kind of list of nodes is it then?

Answer (score 1):

The error message links to various custom node list implementations. From looking at *that* code, you might see a method `last()` on the node list class. Do something like `nodelist.last()` to get the last list element.

It will call `trailer.getPrev()` internally, and if it works, then *your* trailer does not point to the real trailer position.

Comment: 7? I don't see a 7 in your list!? We **need** to see the relavant code and we need the (fully qualified) name of your node list class.